# Find distinct groups $G$ and $H$ such that each is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of the other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give an example of two groups $G_1$, $ G_2$ such that $G_1$ embed in $G_2 $ and $G_2$ embed in $G_1$ ($H$ embed in $G$ means that there exist $K$ a subgroup of $G$ s.t. $K$ and $H$ are isomorphic), but $$G_1≇G_2.$$ ($G_1≇G_2$ $⟺$ $\nexists f:G_1\to G_2$, $f$ 1-1, onto and homomorphism.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you accepted the answer about free groups, when apparently you haven't learnt about free groups?  It's a good answer, but surely not the answer expected if this is a homework problem for a course which hasn't covered free groups yet.

Comment: So how do you know the answer is true?

Comment: Sure, but all that doesn't really help with your homework or your understanding, does it?

Comment: it doesn't help me now ,but it force me to study  about free group. and im sure i will understand it

Comment: Ah, okay, great, if you're going to follow it up and figure out why it's true for yourself, then that's fine!  (And in fact the answer does help, because it tells you what to learn about.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take two free groups of rank 2 and 3.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this:

$$G_1=\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_{5^2}\times \mathbb Z_{5^3}\times \mathbb Z_{5^4} \times \cdots$$
$$G_2= \mathbb Z_{5^2}\times \mathbb Z_{5^3}\times \mathbb Z_{5^4} \times ...$$

$G_2$ is embedded in $G_1$, since $G_2 \cong \{0\} \times \mathbb Z_{5^2}\times \mathbb Z_{5^3}\times \mathbb Z_{5^4} \times \cdots$ ; and $G_1$ is embedded in $G_2$ since $G_1 \cong 5G_2$.

Comment: I like this very much, because I'm fairly sure it doesn't require anything beyond what the OP would have already learnt.

Comment: @TaraB This kind of examples are classical: see, for instance, Kaplansky's book *Infinite Abelian Groups*, page 13.

Comment: @YACP:  Yes, sure, it's an obvious idea.  I just wanted to comment because I thought it was a particularly suitable one, and other than commenting I couldn't do more to express my approval than upvote.

Comment: @YACP, since I'm not a group theorist, it took me a while to come to this example.And I was wondering, is there a straightforward argument to explain that these two groups are not isomorphic? I thought that they aren't because in $G_1$ there is an element of order $5$ which is not a fifth power of any other element, and in $G_2$ there are no such element. Sounds OK?

Comment: @Ludolila:hi your answer is nice but i don't know why $G_1$ and $G_2$ aren't isomorphism ? please determine this element of order 5 which is not a fifth power of any other element, and in G2 there are no such element.and complete your claim

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo:  The element Ludolila is referring to in $G_1$ is the generator of the first $\mathbb{Z}_5$ factor.  You probably know enough about abelian groups to prove that every element of $G_2$ of order $5$ is a power of some other element?

Answer (score 3):

By using the theorem of classification of divisible groups, we can easily proved that the claim is true, but if we omit the adjective *divisible*, the claim fails. If fact, as @Boris noted correctly, by taking two free groups of different rank$>2$ or equal to $2$ you can see the claim proved. See this also [Is this statement true for divisible Groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37802/8581) and [Exercises in Abelian Group Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=0qL_ujgd2esC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=if+G+and+H+are+divisible+groups+each+of+which+is+isomorphic&source=bl&ots=fX1nCRdhMV&sig=ZkUohXOpeemIXUVklSrKarKm1l4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2OQsUbeIE6GF4ATwqoDACQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=if%20G%20and%20H%20are%20divisible%20groups%20each%20of%20which%20is%20isomorphic&f=false) page 155 for more.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: Hi, In what source did you face this problem? Some problems might have answers in the other area where you had expected.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: Note that we will have troubles if we want to find such these groups among finite groups. Right? So, we look for an infinite structures.

Comment: @BabakS.:  The way you've writted this answer isn't that clear, because there isn't really a 'claim' in the question, but insofar as there is one, it's that there _do_ exist two non-isomorphic groups which are isomorphic to subgroups of each other.  And you are using 'the claim' to mean the opposite.

Comment: @TaraB: I found this question in the book of Rotman. There, he wanted me to prove the claim just for divisible groups and in the rest; he asked me to verify what would be happened if we omited the divisibility. Thanks

Comment: @BabakS.:  I don't quite understand how what you said relates to what I said.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: Hi. Do you agree that $5\mathbb Z_5=\{0\}$?